Storing piece attacks for bitboards
I know that to store the knight's attacks for example I begin by initializing an array of 64 uint64s representing all the possible knight attacks and fill it up then whenever I need the move of a knight I can just get its index in the array of attacks but that only works for knights, how would I do it for other pieces such as pawns?
Example of how to get knight moves:
std::array<uint64_t, 64> getKnightAttacks()
{
    const uint64_t notLeft2Mask   = 0x3f3f3f3f3f3f3f3f;
    const uint64_t notLeftMask    = 0x7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f;

    const uint64_t notRight2Mask  = 0xfcfcfcfcfcfcfcfc;
    const uint64_t notRightMask   = 0xfefefefefefefefe;

    std::array<uint64_t, 64> knight_attacks{};

    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    {
        uint64_t pos = (uint64_t)1 << i;
        uint64_t temp_attacks = 0;

        temp_attacks |= (pos << 6) & notBottomMask & notRight2Mask;  // noWeWe
        temp_attacks |= (pos << 15) & notBottom2Mask & notRightMask; // noNoWe
        temp_attacks |= (pos << 17) & notBottom2Mask & notLeftMask;  // noNoEa
        temp_attacks |= (pos << 10) & notBottomMask & notLeft2Mask;  // noEaEa

        temp_attacks |= (pos >> 6) & notTopMask & notLeft2Mask;   // soEaEa
        temp_attacks |= (pos >> 15) & notTop2Mask & notLeftMask;  // soSoEa
        temp_attacks |= (pos >> 17) & notTop2Mask & notRightMask; // soSoWe
        temp_attacks |= (pos >> 10) & notTopMask & notRight2Mask; // soWeWe

        knight_attacks[i] = temp_attacks;
    }

    return knight_attacks;
}


The same way except that some pawn moves (diagonally) are only possible iff it is a capture and captures en passant onto the third or seventh rank invariably catches everyone out at some stage. Equally pawns can only move without a capture into empty squares 1 or 2 ahead so that they are pretty much the odd man out and have a colour handedness in addition.

For pawns you need to handle normal moves, double moves, captures, en passant, and promotions all separately. The benefit is that you can perform each of these for all pawns at once with one or two shifts, instead of iterating all pawns.
